# Custom directory scanner for sftp-inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Our application will be reading and writing files to FTP folder with directory structure {date}/{usercode}/*. We are trying to use sftp inbound adapter.

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="sftpInboundAdapter"
        channel="filesIn"
        filename-pattern="*.xml"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        remote-directory="file:${fileserver.input.path}"
        local-directory="file:${fileserver.output.path}"
        delete-remote-files="false"
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

is there a way to set custom directory scanner for sftp inbound adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom scanner is not currently supported.

As a work-around, you can set the `ouput-channel` to `"nullChannel"` and configure a separate `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter/>` with a custom scanner.

Comment: Thanks Gary!. So, <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter> will move files from remote to local directory and post the messages to null channel. From local directory we use <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter/> with directory scanner. But int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter does'nt scan the sub directories and i will be able to download only the files as per the below link. "http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/88372-sftp-inbound-adapter-and-subdirectories". So there is no point in using custom scanner.

Comment: The inbound adapter doesn't have a "remote" scanner; just a local one. If you want to fetch a remote directory tree, use an [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) using the recursive MGET option.

Comment: My requirement is to delete the source files in remote location after the download. So if we use MGET the source files wont be deleted. Also i want only the downloaded files to be deleted because the source directory gets updated continuously. Is there any solution for this scenario?

Comment: You can send the results to a splitter and then to another gateway that uses the RM command; you can also do them one at a time with a recursive LS, splitter, GET, RM - see the [ftp sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp), which doesn't use a recursive `ls` but the technique is the same.

Comment: Thanks Gary!. While using splitter, we are sending the files for delete and download. will both the functions gets executed parallely?. In that case, what if the file  which is getting downloaded is selected for delete?.

Comment: The `rm` will run on the same thread as long as you don't use queue or executor channels. `ls->split->get->rm` will get and remove the files one at a time; `mget->split->rm` will remove the files after they've all been fetched.